# You are all "but" forced to do something instead of something else

Tags: meaning, word-choice, conjunctions

What is the grammatical usage of "**but**" in this sentence?

> You are all **but** forced to use them instead of standard C++

Could we ignore "**but**" and yet convey the same meaning?

> You are all forced to use them instead of standard C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**All but** is an expression meaning almost.

So "all but forced" is like saying "You are not actually forced. However you are urged, encouraged, advised, suggested, persuaded, recommended…"

Answer (score 9):

The two sentences have different meanings, along the following lines:

> You are all but forced to use them  == One is almost required to use them
>   You are all forced to use them == All of you people here must use them

*[All but](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_but)* is serving as an adverb in your example, with meaning *almost* or *nearly*.